# Sorting on numerical model attribute in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I've got a very basic `Price` model that looks like this:

```
App.Price = DS.Model.extend({
    value: DS.attr()
});

App.Price.reopenClass({
    FIXTURES: [
        { id: 1, value: 29.99 },
        { id: 2, value: 39.99 },
        { id: 3, value: 49.99 },
        { id: 4, value: 55.99 }
    ]
});
```

Here's the route that's using this model:

```
App.PricingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.find('price');
    }
});
```

In the controller, I set the sorting to be based on the `value` attribute:

```
App.PricingController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    sortProperties: ['value'],
    sortAscending: true
});
```

Then my template (in Jade) where I want them to be display in sorted order:

```
{{#each price in this}}
    li.price-levels__value {{price.value}}
        .price-levels__remove("{{action 'delete' price.id}}")
{{/each}}
```

Problem is they're not sorted. Interesting fact is that if I change the type of the `value` attribute to strings, the sorting DOES work.

eg.

```
{ id: 1, value: '29.99' }
{ id: 2, value: '39.99' }
etc.
```

So how do I get the sorting to work on a numerical model attribute?

Comment: Which version of Ember are you using? Can you get it to fail in this example? http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cicihu/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I'm using Ember 1.9.1, the same as in your example. Your example helped me realize that on initial output it IS ordering them correctly, but when I create a new record, it is displaying at the bottom of the list rather than inserting in the proper location. This described behavior DOES occur when the value is a string, but not when it is an integer. Any ideas?

Comment: can you duplicate that in my jsbin example above and post a link? I can then take a look

Comment: Ok, I've added it to your jsbin! There's a form there now that creates a new record on submission. The new record is automatically added to the list, but just appended to the end instead of being sorted. Let me know what you think I'm missing. Thanks so much!

Comment: And I think I've just figured it out. Or at least a workaround... I have to take the value from the form and run it through parseFloat when I assign it to the model. That seems to do the trick. How can I give you credit for helping to solve this?

Comment: Not sure, but don't worry about it - I am glad you figured it out. :)